# BitLocker dialog: disable the "Show password characters as I type them" checkbox option

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

Is there a way to turn off or otherwise disable the below option/checkbox on the initial BitLocker dialog that pops up when you insert a BitLocker-encrypted USB key?

If the checkbox is checked -- even after characters are entered in the textbox -- the password characters are shown on the screen.

Screengrab of default BitLocker dialog with some characters entered, display shows "***********":

[image: type in password nice and hidden]

Screengrab once checkbox is checked, after the characters above entered, display shows "omg!kittens"

[image: check the box and voila!]

The [Black Helicopters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_helicopter) will *clearly* see my password if my kitten happens to pounce at an inopportune time.  Seriously, this is a pretty ugly, though perhaps small, security issue in my opinion.  You start typing... sneeze or get distracted... someone sitting at your desk just has to hit "Tab" then "Space" and they get the goods.

For reference, this is under Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to disable that, aside from hacking the program or some other means. It's a 'feature'. TrueCrypt has the same thing in it's initial dialog.

Comment: Really?  No registry hack to change the behavior of the BitLocker dialog?  I was hoping for an undocumented reg hack as you mention.  Please, think of the kittens.

Comment: I think you're SOL on a 'fix'. If you have people sitting that close to your keyboard that they can get your password when you sneeze, I suggest you consider moving your desk.

Comment: @Justin Pearce - It's the principle of having a way to change an already-entered "hidden" password field to plain text at the click of a checkbox.  Especially for something that is marketed as a security improvement such as BitLocker.  Thanks for your replies on this!

Answer (score 0):

Overall, the answer is that aside from hacking the Bitlocker program itself, it isn't going to happen.