# Windows 7 style "Show password" in Windows 8.1 Bitlocker

Tags: windows-8.1, bitlocker

Windows 7 had a really nice feature for those of us with very long passwords on our Bitlocker drives (i.e. *dozens* of characters long).  You could click a check box and type your password while being able to see the characters in plain text ([A picture of what I'm talking about is in this post](https://superuser.com/questions/273922/bitlocker-dialog-disable-the-show-password-characters-as-i-type-them-checkbox)).

Is there a group policy or registry hack that will restore this functionality to Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what you want is not possible.

You can temporarily show the clear text password by clicking on the eye at the right of the password box. But not toggle it like you would like.

You can also disable the password reveal button by using the registry or by GPO, but not the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

So Alex G. is correct. Microsoft dumped the functionality in Windows 8.

Here is what I did as a workaround:

I wrote a PowerShell script that gives me the functionality I want.  It's not ideal because you have to run the script as an admin and it's an old style looking VB message box but given how long my password is it's a huge productivity gain for me to be able to see it. YMMV.

The PowerShell script is below (you'll want to change the mount point to whatever your encrypted drive is on):

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

function Read-InputBoxDialog([string]$Message, [string]$Title, [string]$DefaultText)
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
    return [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($Message, $Title, $DefaultText)
}



$clearText = Read-InputBoxDialog -Message "Enter your password" -Title "Bitlocker Unlock" -DefaultText "Password"
$ss = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $clearText -AsPlainText -Force

Unlock-BitLocker -MountPoint 'G:' -Password $ss

Remove-Variable -Name ss
Remove-Variable -Name clearText
```